# Iframe Input has uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have an input inside an iframe that I would like to put in a preloaded value after the page has loaded.  I've put in this code so far:

```
<script>
    jQuery('iframe').load(function(){
             jQuery('iframe').contents().find('input#ysi_subject').bind('change',function(e)     {
            var title_name = "DO I LOOK LIKE I'M WORKING?";
            jQuery('input#ysi_subject').val(title_name);
         });
    });
</script>
```

but when I look at the console log, I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Can anyone help explain why it's not catching the input?

Comment: Probably due to scope, it executes the method still in the parent document would be my guess. See if `$(this).val(...)` works,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to access the DOM prior to the DOM elements actually being loaded, so any references to the DOM in this case will output `null`. Place the code in a `$(document).ready()` handler in order for this to work:

```
... <!-- jQuery reference -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // your code that you are trying to run
    });
</script>
```

* Note that I simplified it down to show what I am really talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The change event is firing from within the iframe back to the parent window.
$("input#si_subject") does not exist in the parent window.

```
    jQuery('iframe').load(function(){
       jQuery('iframe').contents().find('input#ysi_subject').bind('change',function(e)      {
         var title_name = "DO I LOOK LIKE I'M WORKING?";
         // this would work            
         jQuery('iframe').contents().find('input#ysi_subject').val(title_name);
         // this is better
         $(this).val(title_name);
       });
    });
```